# Problema con codificación UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, codificación

Buenas tardes,

No sé por qué estoy teniendo problemas con los caracteres de mi página web cuando los cargo desde la base de datos. Así salen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la clase Sistema con la conexión a la base de datos:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

class Sistema {

    protected $db;

    protected $total = 0;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function dbconnect() {

        $host_name = 'localhost';
        $database = 'mycbs';
        $user_name = 'root';
        $password = '';

        $options = array(
            MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
        );

        $pdo = null;
        try {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$database;", $user_name, $password, $options);
          $this->db = $pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
          die();
        }



    }

}
```

En todas las páginas:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Y la codificación en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe si me estoy olvidando de algo o que puede estar sucediendo?

Usando utf8_encode(); me funciona perfectamente, pero es un coñazo ponerlo en todo el código, ya que la página entera imprime datos desde php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Si es para MySQLi Procedural `mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');`](/a/580975)

Este fue el que me resolvió el problema de un día de investigación. Programo en PHP con JavaScript y utilizo JSON para acceder a los datos de la base.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Buenas noches, la codificación debe ser esta si es español, Saludos

Comment: Ya tiene esa codificación, lo especifica en la pregunta. Además esto es de hace un año y medio casi. Si te fijas ya hay una respuesta que resolvió el problema.

Answer (score 0):

coloca en el string de conexión "charset=utf8". si no utiliza $pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8');

quedaría algo así

```
    try {
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $user_name, $password, $options);
      //en caso que no te funcione lo del charset en el string de conexión
      $pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
      $this->db = $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
      die();
    }
```

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la codificación en la cual se guarda el archivo donde escribiste el código o todos los archivos incluidos para que todos sean utf8

revisa que el campo de la base de datos no tenga guardada la cadena incorrectamente esto sucede cuando la codificación del script que guardo el archivo es incorrecta.

Las cosas que debes tener en cuenta para la codificacion en paginas web es:

1. El meta en el codigo de la pagina
2. La codificación en la cual se guarda el archivo y todos los archivos
   incluidos (esto es en tu editor)
3. La codificación por defecto del servidor (puedes cambiarlo para el
   script con la funcion    header)
4. La codificación de la base de datos (el schema,la tabla,la
   columna)
5. La codificacion que indicas al cliente (PDO)
6. Si antes de    imprimir la cadena usas alguna función como
       htmlentities() especifica    explícitamente la codificación a utf8. revisa el manual de php [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) ojo
   esto depende de la versión de php lee atentamente la documentación

Comment: 1. Esta bien 2. No sé a que se refiere. Uso Dreamviewer 3. Perfecta 4. Todo en utf8_unicode_ci 5. Perfecto 6. No uso htmlentities, uso echo para imprimir todo. No sé que puede estar pasando para que no funcione las tildes...

Comment: 2. Todos los archivos de texto tienen una codificación en la cual se guardan esto lo indica en el mime normalmente la codificación del sistema. revisa las propiedades del archivo. y verifica que este en utf8. tu editor debe tener la opción para ello

Comment: si la cadena del problema es resultado de la consulta sql es probable que ese no sea el problema. eso te afecta si la cadena es producto de una cadena constante ejemplo echo "hola á".  Si el texto es resultado de la consulta verifica que el texto este bien en la base de datos.  consultando la cadena desde workbench o phpmyadmin. la función  htmlentities es un ejemplo verifica otras funciones que pueden estar afectando.

Comment: Usa esto como option en pdo: **$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES UTF8');** observa la diferencia con lo que has definido. sin el **PDO::** la constante es global y no es constante de la clase PDO

Comment: Usando $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES UTF8'); ha corregido el error. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Me ha vuelto a salir un problema. Ahora al insertar en una base de datos, no reconoce las tildes, y las nuevas entradas al imprimirlo, tampoco imprime las tildes. https://gyazo.com/faf585fdb93a65afd1c7213980d9f436

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67338/discussion-between-sergio-cauich-and-charlie-clewer).

Answer (score 0):

Aqui las tres maneras que he encontrado para poder conectarme a la DB sin problemas de acentos y eñes, basicamente tomado de https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp y de https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php

Si es para PDO :

```
<?php
class Conexion
{
    public static function Conectar()
    {
        define('servidor', 'localhost');
        define('nombre_bd', 'nombre_DB');
        define('usuario', 'nombre_usuario');
        define('password', 'el_password');
        $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=" . servidor . "; dbname=" . nombre_bd, usuario, password, $opciones);
            return $conexion;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("El error de Conexión es: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Sie es para MySQLi Procedural:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "nombre_usuario";
$password = "el_password";
$database = "nombre_DB";

// Creamos la conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Cambia el juego de caracteres para que lea acentos
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');
?>
```

Si es mysqli orientada a objetos (MySQLi Object-Oriented):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "nombre_usuario";
$password = "el_password";
$database = "nombre_DB";

// creamos la conexion
$conexion = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Cambia el juego de caracteres para que lea acentos
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');
?>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Comunidad he puesto los enlaces que llevan a la fuente de la respuesta :)